# api demos/app/preferences/1.preferences from xml

Tags: xml, sharedpreferences, preferences, android

I want to use "API Demos/app/preferences/1.preferences from XML" layout in my application but i don't know where to find the source files .
I searched in API Demos samples but i could only find .java files not layouts.

Answer (score 1):

The preference xml is under /res/xml folder. You can checkout the res -> xml -> preferences.xml in the apidemos.